# Scraping Unicode(non ASCII ) content from HTML Python code not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have some Html files containing Unicode content. I need to extract the content.

This is my code, it is not working

```
import os
from urllib import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url= "http://www.dinakaran.com/News_Detail.asp?Nid=76468"
raw = urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(raw,'lxml')
texts = soup.findAll(text=True)

def contains_unicode(text):
    try:
        str(text)
    except:
        return True
    return False

result = ''.join((text for text in texts if contains_unicode(text)))
```

Output:

```
   0\xb4\xb0\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe2\x80\x8d\xe0\xb4\xa4\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\xa4\xe0\xb4\xbe\xe0\xb4\xa4\xe0\xb4\xbe\xe0\xb4\xb0\xe0\xb4\xae\xe0\xb4\xbe\xe0\xb4\xaf\xe0\xb4\xbf</a>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<li class="news-item">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<a href="http://boolokam.com/archives/122790" rel="bookmark" title="Permalink to \xe0\xb4\x87\xe0\xb4\xb5\xe0\xb4\xb0\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe2\x80\x8d\xe0\xb4\x95\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\x95\xe0\xb5\x8d \xe0\xb4\x85\xe0\xb4\xa4\xe0\xb4\xbf\xe0\xb4\xb8\xe0\xb5\x81\xe0\xb4\xa8\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\xa6\xe0\xb4\xb0\xe0\xb4\xbf\xe0\xb4\xae\xe0\xb4\xbe\xe0\xb4\xb0\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe2\x80\x8d \xe0\xb4\x86\xe0\xb4\x95\xe0\xb4\xbe\xe0\xb4\xae\xe0\xb5\x86\xe0\xb4\x99\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\x95\xe0\xb4\xbf\xe0\xb4\xb2\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe2\x80\x8d \xe0\xb4\x87\xe0\xb4\xa8\xe0\xb4\xbf \xe0\xb4\x8f\xe0\xb4\xa4\xe0\xb5\x8a\xe0\xb4\xb0\xe0\xb5\x81 \xe0\xb4\xaf\xe0\xb5\x81\xe0\xb4\xb5\xe0\xb4\xa4\xe0\xb4\xbf\xe0\xb4\x95\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\x95\xe0\xb5\x81\xe0\xb4\x82 \xe0\xb4\x87\xe0\xb4\x99\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\x99\xe0\xb4\xa8\xe0\xb5\x86 \xe0\xb4\x86\xe0\xb4\xaf\xe0\xb4\xbf\xe0\xb4\x95\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\x95\xe0\xb5\x82\xe0\xb4\x9f\xe0\xb5\x86?" >\xe0\xb4\x87\xe0\xb4\xb5\xe0\xb4\xb0\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe2\x80\x8d\xe0\xb4\x95\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\x95\xe0\xb5\x8d \xe0\xb4\x85\xe0\xb4\xa4\xe0\xb4\xbf\xe0\xb4\xb8\xe0\xb5\x81\xe0\xb4\xa8\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\xa6\xe0\xb4\xb0\xe0\xb4\xbf\xe0\xb4\xae\xe0\xb4\xbe\xe0\xb4\xb0\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe2\x80\x8d \xe0\xb4\x86\xe0\xb4\x95\xe0\xb4\xbe\xe0\xb4\xae\xe0\xb5\x86\xe0\xb4\x99\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\x95\xe0\xb4\xbf\xe0\xb4\xb2\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe2\x80\x8d \xe0\xb4\x87\xe0\xb4\xa8\xe0\xb4\xbf \xe0\xb4\x8f\xe0\xb4\xa4\xe0\xb5\x8a\xe0\xb4\xb0\xe0\xb5\x81 \xe0\xb4\xaf\xe0\xb5\x81\xe0\xb4\xb5\xe0\xb4\xa4\xe0\xb4\xbf\xe0\xb4\x95\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\x95\xe0\xb5\x81\xe0\xb4\x82 \xe0\xb4\x87\xe0\xb4\x99\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\x99\xe0\xb4\xa8\xe0\xb5\x86 \xe0\xb4\x86\xe0\xb4\xaf\xe0\xb4\xbf\xe0\xb4\x95\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\x95\xe0\xb5\x82\xe0\xb4\x9f\xe0\xb5\x86?</a>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<li class="news-item">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<a href="http://boolokam.com/archives/121540" rel="bookmark" title="Permalink to \xe0\xb4\x8e\xe0\xb4\xa8\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\xa4\xe0\xb5\x81\xe0\xb4\x95\xe0\xb5\x8a\xe0\xb4\xa3\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\x9f\xe0\xb5\x8d \xe0\xb4\xa8\xe0\xb4\xbf\xe0\xb4\x99\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\x99\xe0\xb4\xb3\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe2\x80\x8d \xe0\xb4\x95\xe0\xb5\x81\xe0\xb4\x9f\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\x9f\xe0\xb4\xbf\xe0\xb4\x95\xe0\xb4\xb3\xe0\xb5\x86 \xe0\xb4\xaa\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\xb0\xe0\xb4\xb6\xe0\xb4\x82\xe0\xb4\xb8\xe0\xb4\xbf\xe0\xb4\x95\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\x95\xe0\xb4\xa3\xe0\xb4\x82 ?" >\xe0\xb4\x8e\xe0\xb4\xa8\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\xa4\xe0\xb5\x81\xe0\xb4\x95\xe0\xb5\x8a\xe0\xb4\xa3\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\x9f\xe0\xb5\x8d \xe0\xb4\xa8\xe0\xb4\xbf\xe0\xb4\x99\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\x99\xe0\xb4\xb3\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe2\x80\x8d \xe0\xb4\x95\xe0\xb5\x81\xe0\xb4\x9f\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\x9f\xe0\xb4\xbf\xe0\xb4\x95\xe0\xb4\xb3\xe0\xb5\x86 \xe0\xb4\xaa\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\xb0\xe0\xb4\xb6\xe0\xb4\x82\xe0\xb4\xb8\xe0\xb4\xbf\xe0\xb4\x95\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\x95\xe0\xb4\xa3\xe0\xb4\x82 ?</a>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<li class="news-item">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<a href="http://boolokam.com/archives/120062" rel="bookmark" title="Permalink to \xe0\xb4\xb2\xe0\xb4\xb5\xe0\xb5\x8d \xe0\xb4\xb2\xe0\xb5\x88\xe0\xb4\xab\xe0\xb5\x8d \xe0\xb4\xae\xe0\xb5\x86\xe0\xb4\x9a\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\x9a\xe0\xb4\xaa\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\xaa\xe0\xb5\x86\xe0\xb4\x9f\xe0\xb5\x81\xe0\xb4\xa4\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\xa4\xe0\xb4\xbe\xe0\xb4\xa8\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe2\x80\x8d \xe0\xb4\xaf\xe0\xb5\x8b\xe0\xb4\x97" >\xe0\xb4\xb2\xe0\xb4\xb5\xe0\xb5\x8d \xe0\xb4\xb2\xe0\xb5\x88\xe0\xb4\xab\xe0\xb5\x8d \xe0\xb4\xae\xe0\xb5\x86\xe0\xb4\x9a\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\x9a\xe0\xb4\xaa\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\xaa\xe0\xb5\x86\xe0\xb4\x9f\xe0\xb5\x81\xe0\xb4\xa4\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\xa4\xe0\xb4\xbe\xe0\xb4\xa8\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe2\x80\x8d \xe0\xb4\xaf\xe0\xb5\x8b\xe0\xb4\x97</a>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<li class="news-item">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<a href="http://boolokam.com/archives/118727" rel="bookmark" title="Permalink to \xe0\xb4\xa8\xe0\xb4\xbf\xe0\xb4\x99\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\x99\xe0\xb4\xb3\xe0\xb5\x81\xe0\xb4\x9f\xe0\xb5\x86 \xe0\xb4\x87\xe0\xb4\xa3 \xe0\xb4\xa8\xe0\xb4\xbf\xe0\xb4\x99\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\x99\xe0\xb4\xb3\xe0\xb5\x86 \xe0\xb4\xb5\xe0\xb4\x9e\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\x9a\xe0\xb4\xbf\xe0\xb4\x95\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\x95\xe0\xb5\x81\xe0\xb4\xa8\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\xa8\xe0\xb5\x81 \xe0\xb4\x8e\xe0\xb4\xa8\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\xa8\xe0\xb5\x8d \xe0\xb4\xa4\xe0\xb4\xbf\xe0\xb4\xb0\xe0\xb4\xbf\xe0\xb4\x9a\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\x9a\xe0\xb4\xb1\xe0\xb4\xbf\xe0\xb4\xaf\xe0\xb4\xbe\xe0\xb4\xa8\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe2\x80\x8d 5 \xe0\xb4\xae\xe0\xb4\xbe\xe0\xb4\xb0\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe2\x80\x8d\xe0\xb4\x97\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\x97\xe0\xb4\x99\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\x99\xe0\xb4\xb3\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe2\x80\x8d" >\xe0\xb4\xa8\xe0\xb4\xbf\xe0\xb4\x99\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\x99\xe0\xb4\xb3\xe0\xb5\x81\xe0\xb4\x9f\xe0\xb5\x86 \xe0\xb4\x87\xe0\xb4\xa3 \xe0\xb4\xa8\xe0\xb4\xbf\xe0\xb4\x99\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\x99\xe0\xb4\xb3\xe0\xb5\x86 \xe0\xb4\xb5\xe0\xb4\x9e\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\x9a\xe0\xb4\xbf\xe0\xb4\x95\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\x95\xe0\xb5\x81\xe0\xb4\xa8\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\xa8\xe0\xb5\x81 \xe0\xb4\x8e\xe0\xb4\xa8\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\xa8\xe0\xb5\x8d \xe0\xb4\xa4\xe0\xb4\xbf\xe0\xb4\xb0\xe0\xb4\xbf\xe0\xb4\x9a\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\x9a\xe0\xb4\xb1\xe0\xb4\xbf\xe0\xb4\xaf\xe0\xb4\xbe\xe0\xb4\xa8\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe2\x80\x8d 5 \xe0\xb4\xae\xe0\xb4\xbe\xe0\xb4\xb0\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe2\x80\x8d\xe0\xb4\x97\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\x97\xe0\xb4\x99\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\x99\xe0\xb4\xb3\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe2\x80\x8d</a>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<li class="news-item">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<a href="http://boolokam.com/archives/98502" rel="bookmark" title="Permalink to \xe0\xb4\x95\xe0\xb5\x8b\xe0\xb4\xb3\xe0\xb5\x87\xe0\xb4\x9c\xe0\xb5\x8d \xe0\xb4\xb9\xe0\xb5\x8b\xe0\xb4\xb8\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\xb1\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\xb1\xe0\xb4\xb2\xe0\xb5\x81\xe0\xb4\x95\xe0\xb4\xb3\xe0\xb4\xbf\xe0\xb4\xb2\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe2\x80\x8d \xe0\xb4\xa4\xe0\xb4\xbe\xe0\xb4\xae\xe0\xb4\xb8\xe0\xb4\xbf\xe0\xb4\x95\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\x95\xe0\xb5\x81\xe0\xb4\xa8\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\xa8 \xe0\xb4\xaa\xe0\xb5\x86\xe0\xb4\xa3\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe2\x80\x8d\xe0\xb4\x95\xe0\xb5\x81\xe0\xb4\x9f\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\x9f\xe0\xb4\xbf\xe0\xb4\x95\xe0\xb4\xb3\xe0\xb4\xbf\xe0\xb4\xb2\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe2\x80\x8d \xe0\xb4\xb8\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\xb5\xe0\xb4\xb5\xe0\xb4\xb0\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe2\x80\x8d\xe0\xb4\x97\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\x97\xe0\xb4\xb0\xe0\xb4\xa4\xe0\xb4\xbf \xe0\xb4\xb5\xe0\xb4\xb0\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe2\x80\x8d\xe0\xb4\xa6\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\xa7\xe0\xb4\xbf\xe0\xb4\x95\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\x95\xe0\xb5\x81\xe0\xb4\xa8\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\xa8\xe0\xb5\x81 !" >\xe0\xb4\x95\xe0\xb5\x8b\xe0\xb4\xb3\xe0\xb5\x87\xe0\xb4\x9c\xe0\xb5\x8d \xe0\xb4\xb9\xe0\xb5\x8b\xe0\xb4\xb8\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\xb1\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\xb1\xe0\xb4\xb2\xe0\xb5\x81\xe0\xb4\x95\xe0\xb4\xb3\xe0\xb4\xbf\xe0\xb4\xb2\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe2\x80\x8d \xe0\xb4\xa4\xe0\xb4\xbe\xe0\xb4\xae\xe0\xb4\xb8\xe0\xb4\xbf\xe0\xb4\x95\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\x95\xe0\xb5\x81\xe0\xb4\xa8\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\xa8 \xe0\xb4\xaa\xe0\xb5\x86\xe0\xb4\xa3\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe2\x80\x8d\xe0\xb4\x95\xe0\xb5\x81\xe0\xb4\x9f\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\x9f\xe0\xb4\xbf\xe0\xb4\x95\xe0\xb4\xb3\xe0\xb4\xbf\xe0\xb4\xb2\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe2\x80\x8d \xe0\xb4\xb8\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\xb5\xe0\xb4\xb5\xe0\xb4\xb0\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe2\x80\x8d\xe0\xb4\x97\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\x97\xe0\xb4\xb0\xe0\xb4\xa4\xe0\xb4\xbf \xe0\xb4\xb5\xe0\xb4\xb0\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe2\x80\x8d\xe0\xb4\xa6\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\xa7\xe0\xb4\xbf\xe0\xb4\x95\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\x95\xe0\xb5\x81\xe0\xb4\xa8\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\xa8\xe0\xb5\x81 !</a>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<li class="news-item">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<a href="http://boolokam.com/archives/103851" rel="bookmark" title="Permalink to \xe0\xb4\xb8\xe0\xb5\x86\xe0\xb4\x95\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe2\x80\x8c\xe0\xb4\xb8\xe0\xb5\x8d \xe0\xb4\xa8\xe0\xb4\xbf\xe0\xb4\xb7\xe0\xb5\x87\xe0\xb4\xa7\xe0\xb4\xbf\xe0\xb4\x9a\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\x9a\xe0\xb4\xbe\xe0\xb4\xb2\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe2\x80\x8d \xe0\xb4\xaa\xe0\xb5\x81\xe0\xb4\xb0\xe0\xb5\x81\xe0\xb4\xb7\xe0\xb4\xa8\xe0\xb5\x8d \xe0\xb4\xb5\xe0\xb4\x9f\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\x9f\xe0\xb5\x8d \xe0\xb4\xaa\xe0\xb4\xbf\xe0\xb4\x9f\xe0\xb4\xbf\xe0\xb4\x95\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\x95\xe0\xb4\xbe\xe0\xb4\x82 !" >\xe0\xb4\xb8\xe0\xb5\x86\xe0\xb4\x95\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe2\x80\x8c\xe0\xb4\xb8\xe0\xb5\x8d \xe0\xb4\xa8\xe0\xb4\xbf\xe0\xb4\xb7\xe0\xb5\x87\xe0\xb4\xa7\xe0\xb4\xbf\xe0\xb4\x9a\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\x9a\xe0\xb4\xbe\xe0\xb4\xb2\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe2\x80\x8d \xe0\xb4\xaa\xe0\xb5\x81\xe0\xb4\xb0\xe0\xb5\x81\xe0\xb4\xb7\xe0\xb4\xa8\xe0\xb5\x8d \xe0\xb4\xb5\xe0\xb4\x9f\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\x9f\xe0\xb5\x8d \xe0\xb4\xaa\xe0\xb4\xbf\xe0\xb4\x9f\xe0\xb4\xbf\xe0\xb4\x95\xe0\xb5\x8d\xe0\xb4\x95\xe0\xb4\xbe\xe0\xb4\x82 !</a>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<li class="news
```

I need Unicode content only
The HTML tags are not removed

Any suggestions ?

Comment: And what are you getting?

Comment: **All** BeautifulSoup text results are Unicode. Do you mean *non-ASCII* perhaps? What result do you expect? What do you get instead? Do you get an exception?

Comment: But in the out put you can find <li class="news

Comment: The content of a file can never be Unicode. Unicode is just a concept, not an encoding.

Comment: @karu: What about unicode.org? Unicode defines codepoints for characters, but if you want to save or read unicode data it has to be encoded. There is no generic unicode storage format. Data can be written as UTF-8, UTF-16 or even ASCII (if you don't need codepoints out of the ASCII range).

Comment: Cite from http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html: "[...]there are several possible representations of Unicode data[...]".

Comment: @Matthias Too much of information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to list only strings that contain non-ASCII values, then use:

```
def contains_nonascii(text):
    try:
        unicode(text).encode('ASCII')
        return False
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        return True

''.join([text for text in texts if contains_nonascii(text)])
```

Note that some text on that page contains both ASCII and codepoints outside of the ASCII range.

Quick demo:

```
>>> for text in texts:
...     if contains_nonascii(text):
...         print text
... 
கெஜ்ரிவாலை பைத்தியக்கார முதல்வர் என்று விமர்சித்த ஷிண்டே | Chief Minister kejriwaal is mad:shinde - Dinakaran
இ-பேப்பர்
தமிழ்முரசு
SUN குழுமத்திலிருந்து வெளிவரும் காலை நாளிதழ்
[....]    
இணையதளம்
நாளிதழ்
மின்னஞ்சல் தொடர்புக்கு
இணையதளம்
செய்திகளை அனுப்ப
Copyright © 2012 all rights reserved to Kal Publications Design, Development and Maintenance by Web team -
```

The last line contains `\xa9`, the © copyright symbol. You can further filter these out by matching non-latin (encode to `latin1` instead of `ASCII`), or you can use a regular expression testing for certain Unicode ranges (such as Tamil) instead.

If you need to reject a line for containing just one printable ASCII character, you need to use a regular expression:

```
import re
_ascii_letters = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z]', flags=re.UNICODE)

def only_nonascii(text):
    return _ascii_letters.search(text) is None
```

would only return `True` if there are no ASCII letters in your input string:

```
>>> for text in texts:
...     if only_nonascii(text) and text.strip():
...         print text
... 
இ-பேப்பர்
தமிழ்முரசு
செய்திகள்
தலையங்கம்
அரசியல்
இந்தியா
தமிழகம்
குற்றம்
உலகம்
அறிவியல்
[....]
முயற்சி
பணவரவு
சிந்தனை
பிரச்னை
அனுபவம்
விளம்பர தொடர்புக்கு
இணையதளம்
நாளிதழ்
மின்னஞ்சல் தொடர்புக்கு
இணையதளம்
செய்திகளை அனுப்ப
```

Comment: Copyright © 2012 all rights reserved to Kal Publications Design, Development and Maintenance by Web team - In the content there are ASCII characters  This is the problem for me

Comment: @karu: you were testing for anything that does **not** have ASCII in it. `©` is not an ASCII character. You need to be more specific in what you need if that doesn't fit your requirements.

Comment: ok, I understand. " all rights reserved to Kal Publications Design, Development" but this is ASCII right why it is displaying there ?

Comment: @karu: because it contains a non-ascii character.

Comment: @karu: Right, letters, numbers? What about punctuation marks? Dots, question marks, dashes? Be specific.

Comment: Ok. Only letters are problem for me, rest no problem

Comment: Maybe you need to run the contains_nonascii check on individual Unicode characters, not on entire strings that may contain both ascii and non-ascii